# Grease Pencil in render view

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

I'm drawing in a 3d scene using grease pencil and I've come across a problem where if I draw on a 3d surface, the grease pencil lines are still able to be seen through the 3d objects.

This is the viewport view...

[image]

And this is the render...

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Z pass enabled in View Layers properties?

Comment: No, I didn’t. But now that I do, my problem is solved. Thanks!